# Visual Studio Code - No code actions available

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to use the import missing methods, modules etc. feature. However, the quick fix (ctrl or cmd +.) doesn't find any code actions in either JS or Python projects. The lightbulb doesn't show up.
[image]

My User settings:

```
{
"workbench.activityBar.visible": true,
"workbench.statusBar.visible": true,
"window.zoomLevel": 0,
"workbench.iconTheme": "eq-material-theme-icons",
"materialTheme.cache.workbench.settings": {
    "themeColours": "Default",
    "accentPrevious": "Graphite"
},
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {},
"workbench.colorTheme": "Material Theme",
"explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
"python.linting.pylintPath": "/usr/local/bin/pylint",
"python.linting.flake8Path": "/usr/local/bin/flake8",
"editor.renderControlCharacters": false,
"workbench.sideBar.location": "left",
}
```

Workspace settings:

```
{
"python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
"python.linting.pep8Enabled": false,
"python.linting.enabled": true,
"python.pythonPath": "env/bin/python"
}
```

Comment: first, I am not sure VSCode support automatic import for python. Second, it does not seem like you are following the packaging rules strictly (https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), although I believe with pure python files on the project root they get recognized as packages, as __init__.py maps the scope of multiple files to a structure the interpreter understands as a single python module

Answer (score 0):

For Python projects:

Try opening the settings for Pylance; in the settings searchbar, type `@ext:ms-python.vscode-pylance`.
Then check the setting `Python > Analysis:Auto Import Completions`.

For JS projects:

The "JavaScript (ES6) code snippets" extension reacts when you type certain strings, followed by a TAB keypress. Several of them are shortcuts for `import` statements.